# How to parse non-array JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to read json from a local .json file and parse the contents using `StreamReader` and `Json.NET`. Json & my code:

```
contents of .json file: {"rate":50,"information":{"height":70,"ssn":43,"name":"andrew"}}

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToJsonFile))
                {
                    dynamic jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    foreach(var item in jsonArray)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine(item.rate);
                       Console.WriteLine(item.ssn);
                    }
                }
```

This gives me an error on the line `foreach(var item in array)`: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I am guessing this is because my json is not actually an array but that is how I am trying to parse it. How can I parse this json in order to pull out fields such as `rate` or `ssn`?

NB - please do not flag this question as a duplicate of [Read and parse a Json File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp), as that is where I got my original code from.

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out in other answers, `jsonArray` is *null*. That explains my error but still does not answer my question. How else can I parse this json in order to extract the desired fields?

Comment: Are you sure about the content of json file? the name andrew is not wrapped in (")

Comment: It should be. Sorry, I have edited the post. Thanks for pointing out that mistake.

Comment: Also as it is not an array, try to access the object property directly first

Comment: I would rather suggest to change your code first and remove the foreach loop. and try to access your values using **jsonArray.rate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

If you want to manually parse out the values, you should try using JObject rather than JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. The following code should work:

```
            dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse("{'rate':50,'information':{'height':70,'ssn':43,'name':'andrew'}}");

            Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["rate"]);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["information"]["ssn"]);
```

However, if you know how the json is structured, you should create a .net class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int rate {get;set;}
    public Information information {get;set;}
}

public class Information
{
    public int height {get;set;}
    public int ssn {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

and then use:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(thestringtodeserialize);
```

That way you can have a strongly typed object.

Comment: On the former of your two examples, I get the exception: `Error reading JObject from JsonReader.Path ", line 0, position 0.`

Comment: user3772119 hmm, I just tried running it again and seems to work for me - I'm using a simple console app with the latest Json.NET from nuget - can you post the code you're running?

Comment: The following code works for me, please make sure the json in the file is exactly: {"rate":50,"information":{"height":70,"ssn":43,"name":"andrew"}}

`var pathtoJsonFile = @"c:\json.txt";
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathtoJsonFile))
   {
    dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

    Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["rate"]);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["information"]["ssn"]);
   }`

Answer (score 1):

In any case, I would check for null (DeserializeObject can obviously return null):

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToJsonFile))
        {
            dynamic jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
            if(jsonArray != null) //new check here
            {
               foreach(var item in jsonArray)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine(item.rate);
                  Console.WriteLine(item.ssn);
               }
            }
```

Comment: Okay, so I just tried that and the `jsonArray` *is* null. However, that does not answer my question: "How can I parse this json in order to pull out fields such as `rate` or `ssn`?"

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing this is because my json is not actually an array

True, the returned object is dynamic, so make use of dynamic:

```
var json = "{\"rate\":50,\"information\":{\"height\":70,\"ssn\":43,\"name\":\"andrew\"}}";
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);


Console.WriteLine("rate: {0}. ssn: {1}", obj.rate, obj.information.ssn);
```

See live sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQYuyX

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's an array?
If that's the format the you expect from Json, maybe you should consider defining a class. 
For example:

```
    class SomeJsonObject
    {
        public int rate {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("information")] //if you want to name your property something else
        public InformationObject Information {get;set;}
    }

    class InformationObject 
    {
        [JsonProperty("height", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)] //some other things you can do with Json
        public int Height {get;set;}
        public int ssn {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
    }
```

This way you can just deserialize it to an object:

```
    SomeJsonObject jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeJsonObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 0):

i would fire up nuget and get the JSON.net package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

http://james.newtonking.com/json

it is well documented and can save you a tonne of work.

see also http://json2csharp.com/

EDIT: you are already using this

Comment: Pretty sure OP is already using JSON.Net, with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` being a method in the library. And fyi, Json2CSharp is not written by the same developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is similar to this [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp) . you can use `JavaScriptSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a null reference (with Json.net 6.0.3) but your code has one obvious bug:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "{'rate':50,'information':{'height':70,'ssn':43,'name':'andrew'}}".Replace('\'', '\"');
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
            dynamic jsonArray = obj;
            foreach (var item in jsonArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.rate);
                Console.WriteLine(item.ssn);
            }
        }

The bug is Console.WriteLine(item.rate) will throw.
Your 'array' jsonArray is not actually an array, it is a dictionary!
Therefore, `item`=the first Key-Value-pair in the dictionary, = `{"rate":50}`.
You can prevent the code from throwing by getting rid of your foreach loop.