# Benefits of using Join-Path over string concatenation

Tags: string, powershell

What is the benefit of using [Join-Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/Join-Path) to create a file path instead of just doing something like the following?

```
$Folder\$FileName
```

Comment: You don't need to check for whether \ exists in either string already

Comment: Actually, direcory separators may be different in different  locales.

Comment: Might be analogous to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070934/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-path-combine-over-concatenating-strings-with (not sure).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 0x5c is the separator but it might look different depending on the code page.

`[char]0x5c` in PowerShell for the curious one...

Answer (score 4):

`Join-Path` benefits:

- Uses the path-separator defined for the provider on which it's running
- Supports more than just filesystems (Certificates, registry, etc)
- Accepts multiple items to join.
- Accepts credentials
- Can resolve the result to a full path if it's relative
- Accepts arguments from the pipeline without a `Foreach-Object` intermediary

Comment: One more for you, now that PowerShell is multi-platform, it joins in an appropriate manner for the operating system.