# Addressing resource files in C#

Tags: file, c#-4.0, resources, addressing

I've added my file into resources with right click -> existing item.
Now I want to copy the added file into another directory like this:

`File.Copy(@"I don't know", @"C:\Users\user-1\Desktop\", true);`

I don't know what I have to write in @"I don't know" part to addressing the added resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *myDir* is the directory of your project, the resources' file has path *myDir\Properties\Resources.resx*.

Now, when you execute a program from Visual Studio in Debug mode, the folder is *myDir\Bin\Debug*.

You have to go up 2 folders and enter the *Properties* folder:

```
var resourcesFileName = "Resources.resx";

var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

var actualResourceFilePath = Path.Combine(
    currentDirectory, "..", "..", "Properties", resourcesFileName);

var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

var newFilePath = Path.Combine(desktop, resourcesFileName);

File.Copy(actualResourceFilePath, newFilePath, true);
```

I suggest you to not use the path separator in the hard-coded way (@"dir1\dir2...").

[Use `Path.Combine` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070934/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-path-combine-over-concatenating-strings-with).