# Change former path to custom path keeping the filename and create a file using stream writer in c#

Tags: c#, path, streamwriter

I am creating multiple files using `StreamWriter`, I want these files to be created in a specific directory

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(File.Create(name + ".txt"));
w.WriteLine(name);
w.Close();
```

here `name` is variable that is used as file name and also to be written in that file, but my problem is I want this file to be created in specific directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        StreamWriter writer = null;
        try
        {

           string folderPath = @"D:\SpecificDirecory\";
           string path =  Path.Combine(folderPath , "fileName.txt");

           if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
           }

           fileStream = new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Create);
           writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
           writer.Write(fileBuilder.ToString());            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Path.Combine` uses the `Path.PathSeparator` and it checks whether the first path has already a separator at the end so it will not duplicate the separators. Additionally, it checks whether the path elements to combine have invalid chars.

Quoted from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32071002/1531476)

Also it would be fruitful to check if you `name` variable contains invalid characters for a filename.

You may first remove invalid characters from `name` variable using [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
string invalidCharsRemoved = new string(name
  .Where(x => !invalidChars.Contains(x))
  .ToArray());
```

Quoted from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270832/1531476)

```
string directory = "c:\\temp";
```

Instead of

```
File.Create(name + ".txt")
```

Use

```
string filename = invalidCharsRemoved + ".txt"
File.Create(Path.Combine(directory , filename ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can include the path too:

```
string path = "C:\\SomeFolder\\";
File.Create( path + name + ".txt");
```

Or Use `Path.Combine` like:

```
File.Create( Path.Combine(path, name + ".txt") );
```

Comment: i have tried this but got error "path format is not correct"

Comment: string ww = (@"U:\scripts\");
     StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(File.Create(ww+name + ".txt"));
                    w.WriteLine(name);
                    w.Close();

Comment: why not use Path.Combine ?

Comment: would you please elaborate path.combine

Comment: see my answer and link posted above

Comment: @AdnanHaider please post the content of `name`

Comment: @AdnanHaider how can you get a "path format is not correct" exception? does `name` hold the entire path to the file? or is it a simple filename string like `"filename"` ??

Comment: @MongZhu  `name` contains some thing like (U:\TDScripts\acchf122_0023

Comment: and due to thisU:\TDScripts\ the files are created on this path not he path specified .how can i remove TDScipts from `name`

Comment: @AdnanHaider I posted a way how to get rid of the old path and inject your own into it. Have a look at my answer

Comment: @AdnanHaider glad to hear. is `!!` a sign of happy excitedness of angryness ?=! :)

Comment: @AdnanHaider If you like to can mark the answer that helped you as accepted. This will help future visitors to see that a thread is closed and has a definite answer. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help. Have a nice day

Comment: @MongZhu i have already marked  everyone's answer as everyone gave a valuable answer  like ankit sharma

Comment: @AdnanHaider that is not what I mean. You have upvoted every answer, but you can only accept 1 answer! choose one and click the check mark below the score of the answer, like described in the post. it will turn green afterwards :)

Answer (score 2):

> `name` contains some thing like `@"U:\TDScripts\acchf122_0023"`

ok according to the new information from your comment you need actually to get rid of the old path and directory.

You can use the [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method to achieve that. After that you can use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to create your own path.

Here is an example to demonstrate this:

```
string myDirectory  = @"C:\temp";

string oldPathWithName = @"U:\TDScripts\acchf122_0023";

string onlyFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldPathWithName);

string myNewPath = Path.Combine(myDirectory, onlyFileName + ".txt");

Console.WriteLine(myNewPath);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `path` for your directory like this :

`string path = @"c:\folder\....";`

Then with the following command:

`File.Create( path + name + ".txt");`

You will get what you want