# underscore surrounded by backslashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to concatenate some file name constituents to make sure if I already have an identically-named file, the new one gets a new name with an underscore and an incremental counter.

I have written the following which I believe should work:

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "MyValues");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "_");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, counter.ToString() + ".csv");
```

After I noticed no file is actually saved, I included `Debug.Log(tempPath)` to see what it returns, and surprisingly I get the following:

```
MyUnityProject/Assets\MyValues\_\0.csv
```

Firstly, why are there `\` instead of `/`?

Also, where are the backslashes surrounding the underscore coming from?

Finally, instead of manually removing them, how could I get the correct syntax back? For example `MyValues_0.csv`, `MyValues_1.csv`, etc...

Comment: Isn't Path.Combine's purpose to include the correct Environment delimiter between each part of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `\` or `/` is used to build a valid path is the whole reason [**why** you even use `Path.Combine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32070934/7111561) at all:

- It uses whatever the  current Plattform/OS understands to combine two strings to a path and thereby makes it plattforms independent.
- It also adds some additional checks if the provided strings are valid path snippets and thereby makes it also saver to use than a simple concatenation.

---

What you do

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "MyValues");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "_");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, counter.ToString() + ".csv");
```

Is assuming that `MyValue` and `_` are folder names.

Use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.6) only for combining folders and the final filename **not** for concatenating the filename itself.

---

What you want to do instead is building the complete filename by string concatenation e.g. using [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.6)

```
string filename = string.Format("MyValues_{0}.csv", counter.ToString());
```

or also [$ (string interpolation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
string filename = $"MyValues_{counter.ToString()}.csv";
```

which are just esier ways of writing

```
string filename = "MyValues_" + counter.ToString() + ".csv";
```

and than use `Path.Combine` only to combine the complete filename with the given system folder path like

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code for the `Path` class available here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,16ed6da326ce4745

We can see that the method `Combine` calls the method `CombineNoChecks` for each pair of string paths and returns the following:

```
return path1 + DirectorySeparatorCharAsString + path2;
```

The value of `DirectorySeparatorCharAsString` is:

```
internal const string DirectorySeparatorCharAsString = "\\";
```

There are also other separators defined in the class so you get the right one according your running platform:

```
// Platform specific alternate directory separator character.  
// This is backslash ('\') on Unix, and slash ('/') on Windows 
// and MacOS.
public static readonly char AltDirectorySeparatorChar = '/';
```

So I wouldn't worry about what the method is returning, it should just work.