# C# JSON to object (or array)

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to get pos 'x' and 'y' from JSON file (a part of STL file with coordinates of polygons) to array or object using newtonsoft package but unsuccessfully.

That looks my original file and converted by [JSON online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmdld.png)

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp) but gives me a lots of errors.

Would you give me some tips or example ?

Thanks in advance

```
  try 
  {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.json"))
      {
          json = reader.ReadToEnd();
          List<vertex> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<vertex>>(json);
      }

      dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
             foreach (var vert in array)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",  vert.x, vert.y);
             }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  } 

  public class vertex
  {
      public double x,y;
  }
```

Comment: Have you any existing code to show?  It would help us help you.

Comment: Have you tried using Newtonsoft.Json?
Also +1 to what @StephenWilson said.

Comment: share sample file to convert

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YK9JKr62

Comment: show vertex class. What goes wrong with the deserialize to `list<vertex>`

Answer (score 0):

The file for deserializing into the class you're using should be in the format

```
[{ "x" : 1.3214, "y" : 0.13241},{ "x" : 3.4324, "y" : 0.324}]
```

For deserializing the file you have, it shoud have a class as:

```
 public class Coordinates {
   public decimal Z { get; set; }
   public List<Point> Polygons { get; set; }
 }
 public class Point{
  public List<vertex> points { get; set; } 
 }
 public class vertex{
   public List<decimal> Vertices { get; set; }
   public decimal x { get {return Vertices?[0]} }
   public decimal y { get {return Vertices?[1]} }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly ;)

```
public class Polygonn
    {
        public List<List<double>> points { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public double z { get; set; }
        public List<Polygonn> polygons { get; set; }
    }


string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("backup.json");
 RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
 json.polygons[polygon].points[0].ElementAt(0)
```

Thanks for everyone!
Regards