# C# JsonSerializationException Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I have problem with json (i never touch json before). My code is basically copy paste of this [Read and parse a Json File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp).

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(RandomUtils.launcherPath() + @"\users.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<Account> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(json);
} 

public class Account
{
    public string users;
    public string username;
    public string type;
    public string uuid;
    public string sessionToken;
    public string accessToken;
}
```

and my json (block at users)

```
{
  "users": {
    "quinn23513@gmail.com": {
      "username": "quinn23513@gmail.com", //Just bug here ill fix later
      "type": "mojang",
      "uuid": "008d8151613d4ef4bf491520f90930c1",
      "sessionToken": "token",
      "accessToken": "Anothertoken"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see any list in your json, you have to fix classes

```
 data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

classes

```
  public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string,Account> users { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string sessionToken { get; set; }
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
}
```

but if you prefer a list , you can use this code

```
    List<Account> listUsers = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["users"]).Properties()
                                             .Select(x => x.Value.ToObject<Account>())
                                             .ToList();
```

or if you have only one user

```
Account account = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["users"]).Properties()
                                 .Select(x => x.Value.ToObject<Account>())
                                 .First();
```

Comment: "email@email.com" can change what did i do?

Comment: @Raiskuy you have to post the real json ,  otherwise nobody will help you

Comment: @Raiskuy try dictionary, see my updated answer

Comment: Json fixed Serge

Comment: @Raiskuy Thanks, but as I understand you have several different emails in one json. Havent' you?

Comment: no i just get the json from api so the json can change. And for your example when i try to get something like username it return nothing `Account user = new Account(); Console.WriteLine(user.uuid);`

Answer (score -1):

No, due to your structure List your json should be like:

```
class SomeClass
{
  [JsonProperty("users")]
  public List<Account> Users {get;set;}
}

//And your call method should have such signature: 
var json = r.ReadToEnd();
var cl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
// use your list like:
cl.Users...
```

Comment: `users` in json is not a list, it is an object (in OP's question)

Comment: @Roman no, looks like it's a collection of users, else it's bad design. Are you always return 1 user?

Comment: it looks like, but it is not. Your answer assumes that json is wrong, but you don't mention it at all and just provide non-working code for existing json. `Are you always return 1 user?` - it is not my question, so you'd better ask OP

Comment: @Roman no, you json looks like the collection of users, which must be included in some class in order to have perfect deserialization

Comment: NOT my json. It shoudl be `[...]` in json to deserialize to list.

Comment: @Roman Does your json file missed [] ? [ { "users": ... , "users": { } ] etc ?

Comment: Not work for the same reason.