# How to access connection string from appsettings.json file using MySQL with Entity Framework Core context class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, console-application, connection-string

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                   .Build();

    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}
```

After scaffolding the MySQL database tables, I don't want to keep the connection string in the context class. It should be fetched from the `appsettings.json` file.

My models generated are in separate class library.

I need a example if this can be achieved with DI pattern

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: creating the configuration in the model creating is not recommended (at least, it's not 'normal').   I would recommend creating a new project from one of the many templates, and following that, rather than trying to create something yourself.