# Can I pass a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject as a parameter for Json Parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am writing a JsonParser in C# (using a [reference from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp)). This might be a simple question, but I am new to C#, and thanks for your help.

I am wondering if a `JObject` can be passed to another function for JSON parsing.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Input.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    foreach(var item in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item Type: {0}", item.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", item.ID);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", item.Age);
    }
}
```

I want to do the JSON parsing in a dynamic approach without creating a POJO. Can I pass the `item` to a function that takes care of the parsing? What will the object type be that I could pass here?

```
static void parseJson() {

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Input.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        foreach(var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item Type: {0}", item.GetType());
            parseItem(item);
        }
    }
}

static void parseItem(JObject item) {
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", item.ID);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", item.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", item.Age);
}
```

Say my Json file is something like this.

```
[
  {
     "ID": "1",
     "Name": "abc"
     "Age": "1"
     "Emails": [
      "abc@def.com",
      "abc123@def.com",
      "abc@ghi.com",
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your code can not be even compilled  parseItem(JObject item) {
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", item.ID);

Comment: This is a snippet of code I shared to show my high-level idea or intention. I want to be able to pass each object I get from Json parsing to a separate function where I can print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code, if your json object has  not nested properties and all properties are primitive

```
static void parseItem(string json)
{
    var item = (JObject)JArray.Parse(json)[0];
    
    foreach (JProperty prop in item.Properties())
    {
        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:  {string.Join(",  ", ((JArray)prop.Value))}");
        else Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.Value}"); ;
    }
}
```

or if your properties are more complicated

```
    var jt = JToken.Parse(json);
    parseItem(jt);

static void parseItem(JToken jt)
{
    var item = (JObject)jt[0];
    var emails = item["Emails"].ToObject<string[]>();
}
```

Comment: My question is, can the `prop` be passed to another function? If so what will be the type of `prop`? Say I want a separate function to take care of printing the `prop` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JObjects, you should use `JObject result = JObject.Parse(json)` instead of `dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

To access the properties of that JObject you would use the syntax `var id = result['ID']`

Comment: But my `JObject.Parse(json)` would return an array of objects.