# I'm trying to fill my List<Class> from a text file using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, class

I have a class called cEspecie like this

```
public class cEspecie
{
    private string name;
    private int lifetime;
    private int movility;
    private int deadto;
    private int type;

public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name= value;
        }
    }
public int Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            type = value;
        }
    }
public int LifeTime
    {
        get
        {
            return lifetime;
        }
        set
        {
            lifetime= value;
        }
    }
public int Movility
    {
        get
        {
            return movility;
        }
        set
        {
            movility = value;
        }
    }
public int DeadTo
    {
        get
        {
            return deadto;
        }
        set
        {
            deadto = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I store some data in a list called

```
List<cEspecie> list = new List<cEspecie>() { 
new cEspecie("Wolf", 100, 10, 0, 0)
new cEspecie("Rabiit", 100, 100, 1, 1), 
new cEspecie("Lion", 200, 10, 2, 2), 
new cEspecie("Tiger", 300, 10, 3, 3),  
};
```

In one of the process of my program i store all the data inside a text file using this:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"../../Archives/TextFilecEspecie.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {   
                sr.WriteLine(item.Name);
                sr.WriteLine(item.Type);
                sr.WriteLine(item.Movility);
                sr.WriteLine(item.LifeTime);
                sr.WriteLine(item.DeadTo);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

the result inside "TextFilecEspecie.txt" was this:

```
Wolf
100
10
0
0
Rabiit
100
100
1
1
Lion
200
10
2
2
Tiger
300
10
3
3
```

now my real, real problem is ... How can i get back the same data to store it in the same list? I'm using c# and wpf and i really dont find an answer.

Comment: `Movility` sounds cool.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to read a line from a text file? How to convert a string to a number? How to loop through the file?

Comment: Actually due to the properties of the class, I dont know how to assign them to each one while reading the text file.

Comment: Maybe you should have delimited the objects to one line then you read each line and `Split` the line on the delimiting char and rebuild your objects.

Comment: as a sidenote calling sr.Close() is not necessary and should be avoided if you use the using statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that this way

```
        var list = new List<cEspecie>();
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string name = reader.ReadLine();
                int type = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                int movility = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                int lifeTime = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                int deadTo = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                list.Add(new cEspecie(name, type, movility, lifeTime, deadTo));
            }
        }
```

note that:

1. int.Parse throw error if the string is not a int, use TryParse the data may not be a int
2. this work only if the file has the correct number of lines

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ, and the `Buffer` extension method from Microsoft's excellent [Ix-Main package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main).

```
var species = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
                .Buffer(5)
                .Select(x => new cEspecie
                {
                    Name = x[0],
                    Type = int.Parse(x[1]),
                    Movility = int.Parse(x[2]),
                    LifeTime = int.Parse(x[3]),
                    DeadTo = int.Parse(x[4])
                });
```

`Buffer(5)` will group every 5 lines into an array.

Comment: Instead of Buffer, you can use implementation from the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Answer (score 2):

This is what serialization and ISerializable are for.

[Here is a quick tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file) that should make it fairly simple.

I might even recommend [JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream), which will write it in JSON format so you could more easily create/edit the objects in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You do the same thing only backwards using [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the file. I won't get into specifics since I'm guessing you can use the learning experience so consider this a point to the right direction and homework :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = File.ReadLines("path").Select(x => new cEspecie(x));
```

in `cEspecie` constructor you can initialize the object using input line.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini This gives you a `List<string>` not a list `List<cEspecie>`... It's the cleanest way to read the file but is far from solving the problem. Also, give the format of the input this isn't a usable solution. If each object was like comma delimited on a single line you could use `ReadAllLines` then do `Select(x => x.Split(',')` then pass the tokens into a constructor and make alist of objects but the way he's readying the ifle doesn't allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is very simple and should work. Do error checking though.

```
List<cEspecie> list = new List<Persona>();  
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../Archives/TextFilecEspecie.txt");

for(int i=0;i<readText.Length/5;i++)
{
    list.Add(new Persona(readText[i*5], readText[i*5+1], readText[i*5+2], readText[i*5+3], readText[i*5+4]));
}
```