# Serializing an object using Json.Net causes Out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-store-apps, json.net, out-of-memory

Disclaimer: I did went through most of the solution provided here but most of them were talking about OOM exception while Deserialization.

I am trying to serialize an object( it's a Tree) into Json using Json.Net. Everything works fine for small objects but i get OOM exception when i try it with large objects. As it works with smaller object of same datatype i am assuming there is no circular reference (I did inspect my data structure for it). **Is there a way where i can convert my object into stream ( this is a Windows Store app ) and generate the Json using that stream ?**

```
 public static async Task<bool> SerializeIntoJson<T>(string fileName, StorageFolder destinationFolder, Content content)
    {
        ITraceWriter traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
        try
        {

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                Error = ReportJsonErrors,
                TraceWriter = traceWriter,
                StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
            });
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(traceWriter);

            StorageFile file = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, jsonString);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(traceWriter);
            logger.LogError("Exception happened while serializing input object, Error: " + nullException.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(traceWriter);
            logger.LogError("Exception happened while serializing input object, Error: " + e.Message, e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In order to convert my object into stream, the code i found out was using a BinaryFormatter which is not available in Windows store app dll's.

Comment: Try using a `JsonSerializer` combined with a `StreamReader` as outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream).

Comment: I did looked at the code and that brought me to the question :  Is there a way where i can convert my object into stream ( this is a Windows Store app )?

Comment: That's what the Serializer does. It takes all of the properties and converts them into strings. In this case instead of returning strings it can deposit them directly into a stream (such as a file stream) so that they are not sitting in memory.

Comment: Ok this worked, i had the TraceListner which was creating strings internally with each serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Maybe Nate Diamond could add an answer so that it can be accepted.  Worked for me too!

Answer (score 11):

It is due to the large amount of records you are trying to serialize, which occupies a large amount of memory. Solutions which I have found for this error is to directly write to the documents using StreamWriter(JsonWriter or TextWriter).

If you have Object use [`TextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter?view=net-6.0):

```cs
using (TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText("LocalJsonFile.json"))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, yourObject);
}
```

If you have a string, use [`StringWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringwriter?view=net-6.0):

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    
using (JsonWriter textWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, yourObject);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Updated Code based on suggestions in the comments on the question**, This works!

```
public static async Task<bool> SerializeIntoJson<T>(string fileName, StorageFolder destinationFolder, Content content)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
                JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();

                ser.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                ser.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                ser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
                ser.Error += ReportJsonErrors;

                ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, content);

                jsonWriter.Flush();

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullException)
        {

            logger.LogError("Exception happened while serializing input object, Error: " + nullException.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            logger.LogError("Exception happened while serializing input object, Error: " + e.Message, e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```