# OData.Client returns null

Tags: web-services, odata

I am trying to fetch all the data for Customer. However, `await mODataClient.For ("Customers").Skip (0).FindEntriesAsync()` returns null. I could not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get *Northwind Customer* data

```
  using Simple.OData.Client;
  private IEnumerable <IDictionary<string,object>> myCustomers;

  mODataClient = new ODataClient ("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

  try 
    {
        myCustomers =await mODataClient.For ("Customers").Skip (0).FindEntriesAsync();
    }
 catch 
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");

    }
```

Comment: I wrote a similar console application and it works well requesting the same base URL and the same entity set as you did. Can you try adding a "foreach" block to enumerate through every item in "myCustomers" and try to print their "CustomerID"?

Comment: since myCustomers is null, it crashes when it attempts to run foreach block.

Comment: Weird, I wrote the following console application and it worked like a charm and it's basically the same as yours:

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

        var customers = client.For("Customers").Skip(0).FindEntriesAsync().Result;

        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customer["CustomerID"]);
        }
    }

Comment: @YiDing-MSFT Any idea of the following question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996406/fecthing-collections-in-odata