# Why can't System.Text.Json serialize MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, memorystream, system.text.json

I have a class with a `MemoryStream` property. When I attempt to serialize it using `System.Text.Json`, I'm getting an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Timeouts are not supported on
> this stream.'

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var sampleText = "Hello, MemoryStream!";
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleText);
memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

var testClass = new TestClass
{
    Stream = memoryStream
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testClass);

public class TestClass
{
    public MemoryStream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: 1. You can write and register a `JsonConverter<MemoryStream>` 2. Switch from `MemoryStream` to `byte[]`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331027/newtonsoft-json-net-how-to-serialize-content-of-a-stream) is for Newtonsoft.Json, but it might work for you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the attempt to read either `ReadTimeout` or `WriteTimeout` (implemented in the base class `System.IO.Stream`) throws this exception (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readtimeout?view=net-8.0)). The serializer attempts to read all the properties, and therefore fails.

You need to provide a manual serialization, as Streams are not intended to be directly serialized. `Stream` inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`, a strong indication that the type is not intended for serialization, but should use by-reference semantics instead.