# Change XML opener(reader) to JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have followed a good tutorial that shows how to make an Automation Framework in C# Selenium. 
The config file is in XML at the moment, but I wanted some more practice and change it to a .json file.

At the moment we are using the namespace System.Xml.XPath; and my question is, are there a similar for JSON? Lets say "System.Json;" that works the same as my XML reader. So I don't need to refactor to much code, or is it unavoidably?

This is how it works at the moment.

```
//Initialize
ConfigReader.SetFrameworkSettings();

public class ConfigReader
{

        public static void SetFrameworkSettings()
        {
            XPathItem aut;

            string strFilename = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\Config\\GlobalConfig.xml";
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open);
            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

            //Get XML Details and pass it in XPathItem type variables
            aut = navigator.SelectSingleNode("AutoFramework/RunSettings/AUT");
            Settings.AUT = aut.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

public class Settings
{
    public static string AUT { get; set; }
}
```

Would be awesome if you could just change this two lines

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator()
```

And the `XpathItem`

Cheers

Comment: I think the following answer about JSON.NET can point you to the correct solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788118/3531995

You can pass a stream to the JSON.NET library but you will also need to update the line ```aut = navigator.SelectSingleNode("AutoFramework/RunSettings/AUT");``` because this is XML specific.

Comment: @thomasvdb Will read! tnx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Newtonsoft.Json` which is available from Nuget.
To "reuse" your current code you would have to make some basic `SettingsConverter` first:

```
public static class SettingsConverter
{
    public static string FromXmlToJson(string xml)
    {
        Settings settings = null;
        // read your xml file and assign values to the settings object
        // now you can "serialize" settings object into Json
        return JsonSerialization.Serialize(settings);
    }

    public static string FromJsonToXml(string json)
    {
        Settings settings = JsonSerialization.Deserialize<MeSettings>(json);
        // save settings using your "xml" serialization
        return xmlString; // return xml string
    }
}
```

To use these methods I'm using this `JsonSerialization` helper class :

```
public static class JsonSerialiation
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serializer(writer, obj);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamREader(stream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str)))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader)
        }
    }
}
```

Above example requires from you to change your `Settings` class from static :

```
public class Settings
{
    public static string AUT { get; set; }
}
```

To instance :

```
public class Settings
{
    public string AUT { get; set; }
}
```

If you prefer to keep it as static. You should use `JObject` from `Newtonsoft.Json` library :

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Settings.AUT = obj.SelectToken("AUT").Value<string>();
```

You can always use `JsonConvert.Serialize<T>()` and `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>()` methods instead of the `JsonSerialization` helper class that I've made but in my opinion the less control you have over your code the bigger the problems will be.

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for the good explanation. I will test this directly