# Communicate between computers through USB cable

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, usb, win-universal-app

Is there a way to have two instances of my UWP app running on two devices communicate with each other using a USB cable? I was looking at [UsbDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice)  and the [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303346(v=vs.85).aspx)  for bulk transfers, but I can't seem to find a way to connect two computers. It looks like it's just for storing files on "regular" USB devices.

So, is there a way to send messages through a USB cable connected to two computers from one instance of an app on one computer to another one on another computer?

Comment: Why USB and not Ethernet? USB cannot work with 2 PCs unless there is an active mediator device included in the "cable". Ethernet could work with only a passive cable - but the PCs must be properly configured.

Comment: Follow http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/connecting-two-pcs-using-a-usb-usb-cable/

Comment: @TurboJ `Why ... not Ethernet?` - Because I didn't know that would be better. Thanks! So how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If you take @Turbo J's suggestion of using Ethernet, one option would be to use [sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) and use some form of data serialiasation - e.g.  JSON ([with JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788118/3111099)), though you'd have to find a way of getting the hostname of the remote computer hosting your app