# How to deserialize a JSON stream to a JToken?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON stream to an JToken object (It could be JObject/JArray/JToken, but referred to as JToken).
I want to use the result as an JToken object, not some other class instance like most examples show.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a `Stream` as a `JToken`, you can use either of the following:

- [`JToken.Load(JsonReader, JsonLoadSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm)
- [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JToken>(JsonReader, JsonSerializerSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1.htm)

First create one or both of the following methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken LoadFromStream(Stream s, JsonLoadSettings settings = default, bool closeInput = true, FloatParseHandling? floatParseHandling = default, DateParseHandling? dateParseHandling = default)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { CloseInput = closeInput })
        {
            if (floatParseHandling != null)
                jsonReader.FloatParseHandling = floatParseHandling.Value;
            if (dateParseHandling != null)
                jsonReader.DateParseHandling = dateParseHandling.Value;
            // You might also need to configure DateTimeZoneHandling, DateFormatString and Culture to fully control loading of dates and times.
            return JToken.Load(jsonReader, settings);
        }
    }       

    public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s, JsonSerializerSettings settings = default, bool closeInput = true)
    {
        // This method taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22689976/3744182
        // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/740230/ygaradon
        // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream
        // And modified to pass in settings and control whether the input stream is closed
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { CloseInput = closeInput })
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
            return ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Given those methods, you can do either:

```
var token = JsonExtensions.LoadFromStream(stream, new JsonLoadSettings {  /* Add your preferred load settings here */});
```

Or

```
var token = JsonExtensions.Deserialize<JToken>(stream, new JsonSerializerSettings { /* Add your preferred serializer settings here */ });
```

Notes:

- Loading with [`JsonLoadSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings.htm) allows you to control whether line position information is loaded (which is stored as an [annotation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_AddAnnotation.htm) and can take significant memory), whether comments are loaded, and how to handle [duplicated property names](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.htm).

  Float format and Date/time recognition settings could be controlled by setting the necessary properties directly on [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm).
- Deserializing with [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) allows control of several parsing options including [whether and how to recognize date/time strings as `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) and [whether to load floats as `double` or `decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatParseHandling.htm).

  Line position information is not loaded when using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JToken>()`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iqt10E).