# Convert a Stream into json value c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have below stream which I get from this line where req1 is of `HttpResponseMessage` type and responseMessage is of type `Stream`. How can I convert this Stream into a json Object. My end goal is to extract values from the specific keys in this json.

```
var responseMessage = await req1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22689976/9423721

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Json.NET serialize / deserialize to / from a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer has a class defined. I didnt want to define different class as my model is dynamic. I found this solution , which worked well and got me the desired result

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseMessage))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var jsObj= serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
// read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
Movie movie1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\movie.json"));

// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
}
```