# Unable to read array data from json file C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to read the data from a json file. The file is stored locally and the format data in this file looks like this.

```
{
"DataToDisplay": [
    {
        "Index Number": "9788189999599",
        "Company Name": "TALES OF SHIVA"

    },
           {
       "Index Number": "9788189999599",
        "Company Name": "TALES OF SHIVA"
    },
    {
       "Index Number": "9788189999599",
        "Company Name": "TALES OF SHIVA"
    }
]
```

}

I am using following code to read the data. The class structure goes like this.

```
 public class DataToDisplayClass
{
    [JsonProperty("DataToDisplay")]
    public List< Books> DataToDisplay { get; set; }
}

public class Books
{
    [JsonProperty("Index Number")]
    public string IndexNumber;
    [JsonProperty("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName;
    
}
```

And I am trying to read code as below.

```
   using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:/Users/ravin/source/repos/Covalience/Helpers/Samplejson.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
          
            DataToDisplayClass _listOfBooks = (DataToDisplayClass)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(DataToDisplayClass));
        }
```

The object "_listOfBooks" is coming up as null. Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Is it the class structure or the way I am reading the data.

[update]
Removed white space from file name.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't swallow an exception somewhere? That space seems suspicious: `.../Covalience/Helpers/Samplejson .json"`

Comment: The name of the file also contains white space. I have fixed it and it still does not works. I will update the question also to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Jas I think the OP just wrote some pseudo code, not his actual code, so that's why you see the typos. But i guess even the pseudo version kinds of shows the gist.

Comment: i would say you are missing a step, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788118/7968203

Comment: Just a suggestion for debugging : Instead of casting to any type, try to see if your stream-reader is properly reading the files. Tho I doubt my thought because if it wasn't able to locate/read the file, it would've broke there, instead of executing next lines

Comment: So I moved the file to some other location(D:file.json) and it started to read the data. I am still not sure what was wrong with the first path but strangely, there was no runtime error. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From the C# [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0):

- By default, fields are ignored. You can include [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#include-fields).
- By default, all public properties are serialized.

So you can convert your fields to properties and it will serialize.

```
public class Books
{
    [JsonProperty("Index Number")]
    public string IndexNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Totally missed that those are fields, not props. Good catch!

Comment: That's a very good catch. I have changed them fields to properties and still can't read it.

Comment: @Jas Just noticed that your path is using backslash instead of forward slash. Try with forward slashes. Are you sure you have the content as text after file read?