# C# deserialize http response JSON as it is streamed

Tags: c#, json, stream, httpresponse

I am trying to find clear documentation on how to deserialize JSON data from an http response as it is written. I am using `HttpClient` like so:

```
using var client = new HttpClient(mySocketsHttpHandler);
// auth setup e.t.c....
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
// get data from response message
```

Currently using bog standard way of reading the JSON (using Newtonsoft):

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var niceObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyNiceObject>(json);
```

Works great but there are some scenarios where the result is particularly large (over the 85kb limit for the LOH, sometimes by a lot). I am trying to optimise and would like to deserialize the JSON as it comes in from the request. `HttpResponse` and `HttpClient` seems to be a bit of a black box, currently I am trying:

```
await using var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
using var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var niceObject = serializer.Deserialize<MyNiceObject>(reader);
```

The idea is to avoid the allocation of a string variable and ideally to buffer sections of the response, as it comes in, live into the JSON reader. So is this:

- Actually parsing the JSON as it comes in? Or is it blocking until the response is complete and the stream is fully allocated?
- Is it even possible to parse JSON from a stream as it is written to?
- If this is not at all the right approach, which is the least resource intensive approach?

Comment: _Is it even possible to parse JSON from a stream as it is written to?_ it doesn’t seem likely, as it’s not probable that the stream would arrive in parseable chunks.

Comment: Your last code block that you are trying is what is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788118/1202807). To do any better, it would have to be specific to the type of data. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net) has some good answers, but specific to a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Json Serialization library that you are using, and since you didn't specify it what i can do is limited, for other questions try to give out as much information as possible

If you are using `System.Text.Json` it does provide a method to des-serialize data from streams directly

```cs
var responseStream = await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(apiurl);
var release = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Release>(responseStream);
```

you can also do it getting the `HttpResponseMessage` first if you want to do validations or anything like this:

```cs
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(apiurl);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // sample validations here
}

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var release = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Release>(responseContent);
```

If you are curious you can check all the overloads here [System.Text.Json JsonSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer)